# The height of the Stack Overflow Blog top bar is too large

Tags: feature-request, blog

On a 13" display the blog's top/nav bars cover about 1/4 of the page and they are sticky. Coupled with the browser GUI, the top third of my screen is non-content and that's not a great experience.

Is there a way to disable the stickiness?

Or maybe design them without as much padding, group them in one bar? I've seen other top bars(e.g. Apple's) that make better use of available space.

[image]

Comment: [Blog bar]: Are you *calling me fat?*

Comment: I'm sorry, [Blog bar]. How about 'padded'? :)

Comment: "Circumference-challenged."

Comment: Put `[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('site-header --not-top'), crap => crap.style.position = 'static')` in a userscript or something I guess.